# CMake mulitple build projects in single tree

Tags: cmake

we use several git repos and our build system is cmake. We have several libraries with unit tests (seperate executables) and several applications (release) that we are going to build. In the moment we solve this by having multiple workspaces and a proper Top-Level CMakeLists.txt for the purpose of the current workspace (e.g. test of library A, test of library B, release for application X)

Now we would like to use a single tree (iso multiple workspaces) that includes all libraries, test code and applications, which means we are able to build everything from single tree.

In principle the core problem here is that we need to "merge" our multiple existing Top-Level-CMakeLists into this single tree.
This seems on first view rather easy, but the problem starts at the point that we want to build libraries with different flavours based on the same tree (e.g. using different compile flags, linker flags).

I will make a simplfiied example with a common cmake tree:

```
tree/
CMakeLists.txt
libA/
    CMakeLists.txt
libB/
    CMakeLists.txt
AppA/
    CMakeLists.txt
AppB/
    CMakeLists.txt
```

So lets say, my both applications are using libA, libB - but in case of AppA I would like to use different flags than in AppB.
Somehow I need to tell CMake to compile libA twice and to associate the right version of libA to my corresponding App.

Any ideas or is it in general not possible to have multiple projects in a single tree with CMake?

Comment: Why do you need to use different flags in the same tree?  Can you do one tree with everything using debug flags and another using everything with release flags, and so on?

Comment: Thats a good point @StephenNewell, this might be the trivial and correct answer. The why this is needed comes from the fact that we use a lot of build-time diversity (defines). Lets say, AppA needs libA in a different flavor as appB. So would need two configurations for AppA and AppB. Might be that this is our core problem. Still would be interested if its possible to have this kind of diversity with CMake (guess not).

Comment: I don't understand what is the real problem here. What are you having exactly trouble with? What research did you do? `but the problem starts` What problem? What have you tried? Why is specifying different compile flags for each target a problem? How exactly did it fail? Please post an [MCVE]. Stackoverflow is not for "any ideas" about a design, rather it's a question&solution site to programming problems. My answer to `Any ideas` is: don't ask SO questions and go implement that. You can have as many projects in a single cmake as you want.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk . Sorry if my problem description is not explicit enough and basically I thought SO can be used to ask questions on design / ideas. How do you specify different compile flags for a single target?

Comment: `How do you specify different compile flags for a single target?` How do you not do it? With `target_compile_flags` you specify flags for a single target and `add_compile_flags` adds flags for all following targets (in this and subdirectories). Remove all `add_compile_flags` if you have them and use `target_compile_flags` only for a good design.

Comment: @KamilCuk: As far as I understand the question, the asker wants to build the same `libA/CMakeLists.txt` multiple times in different configurations (or with different parameters). This is hardly possible within the single tree, because all **targets**, created inside this tree, should have **globally unique** names, and a `CMakeLists.txt` in question unlikely chooses names of the targets according to the configuration. The best way seems to resort to build `libA/CMakeLists.txt` in a **separate tree** using `ExternalProject_Add` or other approaches..

Comment: if you need to build libA in different configurations to support AppA and AppB, then you actually have two libraries.  This is a reason *not* to build AppA and AppB at the same time.  I'm sure somebody could come up with a hacky solution to make this work, but I think you're better off only building things with the same "flavor" at any given time.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, your understanding of my question is fully right. I already expected this as this seems the natural way of cmake.

Comment: @StephenNewell will follow your proposal. We will make it configuration dependent what is build, if this make sense in all scenarios is another question. 

Thanks a lot for all your feedback.